# Mongodb: $march, $project and $filter array to get only the document back

Tags: mongodb

I cannot reconstruct this: [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection).

Remember, there are two id which should match and I want the Image: [] back.
This is my structur.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ee4e57a6e5a926bdeb1e406"),
  "Display" : [
    { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5ee5b7db9245084840dc624f"),
      "Image" : [
      {Document I want},
      {Document I want}]
    }
  ]
}
```

My best try:

```
db.User.aggregate([
{"$match" : 
  {"_id": ObjectId("5ee4e57a6e5a926bdeb1e406")}
},{
  "$project" :{
  "Display" : {
  $filter: {
    input: ObjectId("5ee5b7db9245084840dc624f"),
    as: "id",
    cond: {
      "$Display._id": "$$id"}
  }
}
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your aggregation, you are missing `$eq` operator.

**Aggregation approach:**

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      Display: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Display",
          as: "d",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$d._id",
              100
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPLayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MmPTW9LOHXt)

**Find approach:**

```js
db.collection.find({
  _id: 1,
  "Display._id": 100
},
{
  "Display.$": 1
})
```

[MongoPLayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ld5-7XNpjRQ)

Comment: Ohhhhh, Iam silly. I didn't change the "db.collection."